# htaccess shows "Not Found" if directory does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want rewrite everything that matches `<domain>/something/mypage.htm` to `something.php?pid=mypage`, so I wrote the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).htm$ $1.php?pid=$2
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

On my old webhosting provider, the rules worked as expected, but on the new provider, it says "Not Found" when I try to open `<domain>/something/index.htm` or similar. But when I create a directory called `something`, the rewrite rule works as expected.

Is anyone having any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `MultiViews` is perhaps enabled on the new server and this will conflict with your mod_rewrite directive.

With `MultiViews` enabled and you request `/something/mypage.htm` (when `/something.php` exists as a physical file), mod_negotiation will issue a subrequest for `/something.php/mypage.htm` (that's `/something.php` with path-info of `/mypage.htm`) before your mod_rewrite directive is able to process the request, so no `pid` parameter is passed. (Your directive does not match a dot in the first path segment, so the subrequest by MultiViews does not match.)

The 404 will result from either Apache, if `AcceptPathInfo Off` is set (perhaps in the server config), or from your script because the `pid` parameter is not being passed.

When you create a subdirectory called `something`, MultiViews does not rewrite the request since it already matches *something*, ie. the directory by that name.

You need to ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

NB: MultiViews is not enabled by default on Apache, but some shared webhosts do enable it for some reason. It makes extensionless URLs "magically" work out of the box, but actually causes many more problems if you are not expecting it.